# Setting up a config map in HelidonMP

Tags: java, helidon, helidon-webclient

Team, i Have been trying to create config map for one helidon MP project. I have mounted application.yaml file into the config map but still it is not been considered in the pod.
dockerfile:
FROM fccm-dev.dockerhub-phx.oci.oraclecorp.com/java/jdk:17.0.2

ARG service=helidon-jpa-sample

RUN yum clean all

ADD target/helidon-jpa-sample.jar /app/icpxe/target/helidon-jpa-sample.jar
ADD target/libs/* /app/icpxe/target/libs/

VOLUME /app/icpxe/config

WORKDIR /app/icpxe

RUN mkdir -p /app/icpxe/logs && mkdir -p /app/icpxe/wallet

VOLUME /app/icpxe/${service}/conf
VOLUME /app/icpxe/logs
VOLUME /app/icpxe/wallet

CMD ["sh", "-c", "java -Dconfig.file=/app/icpxe/${service}/conf/application.yaml -jar target/helidon-jpa-sample.jar"]
how to configure configmap in HelidonMP

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was recently answered here.

Refer:
[Accessing kubernetes secret in helidon micro profile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111148/accessing-kubernetes-secret-in-helidon-micro-profile-application/76113695#76113695)

Although the above topic relates to k8s secrets, the approach you need to follow for config map is pretty much exactly the same. Just replace the references to secrets in the answer with configMap equivalents, such as secretKeyRef -> configMapKeyRef etc, and you should be set.

Let me know in comments if anything in my linked answer does not translate directly to your problem.